# Is this a proper way of using 虽然？

Tags: grammar, word-choice, vocabulary

因为锻炼也是我的兴趣，我可以用你的录像学汉语。虽然我还在汉语水平考试级3

Or does 虽然 always need a 但是/可是？And is the structure of the sentence alright, or does it sound too novice?

Comment: Both the traditional 雖然/但是 and 因為/所以 are not found in above sentences. I don't see why 雖然 is used in the last sentence, which is not related to the preceding sentence. 鍛練 should be replaced by 學習.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 因为锻炼也是我的兴趣，我可以用你的录像学汉语。虽然我还在汉语水平考试级3

虽然 mean "although", you can omit 'but' or 'still' because it is implied. In your sentence, it implies '*but* + reason, therefore, I am *still* doing it'

It is more native to start the sentence with 虽然

Comment: Do you mean it is more native to start the whole expression with 虽然? I ask as it seems to already be at the start of the (second) sentence and also given the answer by r13.

Answer (score 3):

因为锻炼也是我的兴趣，我可以用你的录像学汉语。虽然我还在汉语水平考试级3. This sentence is fine, though the phrase started with 虽然 is preferred to be the leading phrase in the sentence, so be sounding more sophisticated:

虽然我还在汉语水平考试级3, 因为锻炼也是我的兴趣，我可以用你的录像学汉语。 (though + because of + so), or

虽然我还在汉语水平考试级別3, 我之所以用你的录像学自汉语, 因为我挑戰是我的性向，(though + but/why + because), or

虽然我还在汉语水平考试级別3, 我可以嚐试經由你的录像学汉语作為一個(種)锻炼，
(though + but).

Comment: I see suiran always in front. The second and third sentence were a little advanced so I had to translate it, but the nature of the sentence changed a bit too much for what I wanted to say. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes, they are slightly different. But since you sounded like the video teaches a level higher than yours, so logically you would say "though I am not there yet, but, because of my nature, so I can take (use) video class as a personal challenge", or "though I am not there yet, but, I can try self-improvement by watching the video and exercise through the lessons".

Comment: Also, please note that in your situation, 挑戰 (challenge a higher mean beyond existing capability) is more appropriate than 锻炼 (training to harden the existing condition). 麼炼 can be a good choice too, as you could be "tortured through" the advanced studies :)

Comment: Your sentence is fine (acceptable) but has two points for critical readers - style (arrangement of phrases) and the choice of word to reflect the fact or situation. Wish you enjoy your journey of learning.

Comment: What I tried to say was 'Since strength training is also one of my hobbies, I can use your videos to practice mandarin, although I'm still hsk 3'

Comment: What is "strength training" to do with practicing language? The former sounds like physical training, the latter is brain exercise. Do you mean you can watch the video during strength training? If that's the case, you shall change to say "Although I am not at that level (or, Though it is beyond my level), I still can watch the video during my strength training to exercise my brain, as both (strength training and learning) are my hobbies." It delivers quite a different message than the original.

Comment: No there is a fitness youtuber called baby carrot or 小萝卜。 And I wanted to comment that I can watch his videos to better my mandarin. lmao

Comment: If you mean the fitness video can help you in both ways, then you shall say "虽然我的中文能力還不夠, 看這個視頻可以同時幫助我的體能訓練, 以及提昇我的中文能力. 運動和學習都是我的興趣.

Comment: About the physical training part I never intended to put in there and the sentence is still above my level I think, but I'll get there eventually 

Comment: You will get there by building your capability a little at a time.